# What exactly are digits in base 2^lg n?

Tags: sorting, math, radix

I have been working on a variety of sorting algorithms and there is this one called radix sort in which I must sort numbers in base 2^(lg n) but I don't know exactly what this is. I mean I know base 2 is binary but with the log n I just don't really get it.

So I was wondering what base 2^(lg n) actually is and in which way it i gonna affect my code.

Comment: Is n the maximum range (in which case 2^(log(n)) would make more sense) or is n the number of elements?

Comment: This is a [statement of complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Answer (score 1):

The question is missing information: what the base of lg() is: and if n is the maximum range of values or if n is number of elements. Also there should be a ceiling (round fraction up to next integer) function in the statement.

Assuming that n is the maximum range of values, where n = max() + 1 - min():

If lg = log2, then it's 2^(ceil(log2(n))), which is n or the next power of 2 > n if n is not a power of 2. If sorting numbers, might as well use counting sort instead of radix sort.

If lg = log4, then it's 2^(ceil(log4(n))). For example if n = 1024, then 2^(ceil(log4(1024))) == 2^5 == 32, and it will take 2 radix sort passes (usually least significant digit first) to sort the data.

If lg = log16, then it's 2^(ceil(log16(n))). For example, if n = 65536, then 2^(ceil(log16(65536))) == 2^4 == 16 and will take 4 radix sort passes to sort the data.

As a side note, on a typical PC (X86 processor), if using radix sort on 32 bit or 64 bit unsigned integers, using 2^8 == 256 is usually fastest, even though it means more passes than using something like 2^16 == 65536.

Comment: In Theoryland, it actually makes sense to perform a base-n radix sort. The cost of a base-b radix sort is O((n + b) log_b U), with U being the largest value, since the number of rounds is log_b U and each round does a counting sort taking time O(n + b). If you pick b = n, then this reduces to O(n log_n U) = O(n log U / log n), which is a pretty good runtime. So it is entirely possible that the OP is being asked to do a base-n radix sort.

Comment: I ran some bench marks sorting 36 million psuedo-random 64 bit unsigned integers. On my system (Intel 3770K, Win 7 Pro 64 bit, Visual Studio 2015, C++ code), doing an 8 pass radix with base 2^8, or bit field sizes {8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8}, took about 1 second. Changing this to {11,11,11,11,10,10} 2^11 | 2^10, 6 passes took about 2 seconds, {16,16,16,16} 2^16, 4 passes took about 2.5 seconds. The issue is having the counts and indexes fitting inside L1 cache along with the input data.

Comment: Oh, absolutely. I ran similar experiments a while back after hearing about base-N being a theoretically optimal radix sort and was surprised when that wasn't the case!

Comment: A base n radix sort on integers would essentially a counting sort.

Comment: It depends on what n is. If n is the maximum value, yes, you're absolutely right. On the other hand, if n is the array size, then this isn't exactly counting sort. (Imagine an array of three numbers, each of which are ten million digits long.)

Comment: Then a radix sort base n would take a relatively long time for ten million digit elements. I updated my answer to ask if if n is maximum range or number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

The notation lg n is a shorthand for log<sub>2</sub> n.

Given that, can you simplify 2<sup>lg n</sup> = 2<sup>log<sub>2</sub> n</sup>?

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. So 2^log2 n is equal to n right. So like I mustn't change anything, just use regular based numbers? I also don't know how you write the log above the 2

Comment: It is indeed equal to n, so you’d imagine writing out your numbers in base n, I suppose.